# How do I get an Ansible template to honor new lines after a conditional

Tags: templates, jinja2, ansible

The template looks like this:

```
solr.replication.master=
    {% if ansible_eth0.ipv4.address == servermaster.eth0 %}
        false
    {% else %}
        true
    {% endif %}

solr.replication.slave=false
```

And the output should look like this:

```
solr.replication.master=true
solr.replication.slave=false
```

What I am actually getting is:

```
solr.replication.master=truesolr.replication.slave=false
```

I understand that Jinja2 strips whitespace, and that ansible is probably configuring this by default. But it does not seem to honor -/+ whitespace tags.

Is there a way to force a line break?

Answer (score 37):

Add the following line to your template at first position:

```
#jinja2: trim_blocks:False
```

Comment: Where did you find this? Documentation reference would be great because I can't find it and I think I need something very similar but not this exactly

Comment: This results in every line that contains only conditionals being printed as a blank line.  Might be ok for some, but...

Comment: @byoungb See [this section of the docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#whitespace-control), and also, [the source](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/1af1205a9c9e884c49f74eb3e75dabbcee1b1967/jinja2/environment.py#L113) for the environment options may be of use.

Comment: Yeah actually I meant to ask where it was documented that you could set jinja2 environment variables as comments at the top of templates.

Comment: documentation about such comment in ansible template: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#notes

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue. I solved it by adding

```
{{''}}
```

to the end of the line, for example:

```
solr.replication.master={% if ansible_eth0.ipv4.address == servermaster.eth0 %}false{% else %}true{% endif %}{{''}}
```

This inserts an empty string literal, with the side effect that whitespace is not stripped.

Answer (score 8):

As you mentioned `-/+` whitespace tags are not honored, nor are [line macros](http://tuxknight-notes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/jinja2/jinja2_design.html#line-statements) enabled (at least not `%%` or `#` or `##`).

`trim_blocks` is enabled in ansible. The only thing that I found that does work, is that `trim_blocks` ignores only the first newline

For your example, just adding an extra newline should be sufficient

```
solr.replication.master={% if ansible_eth0.ipv4.address == servermaster.eth0 %}false{% else %}true{% endif %}

solr.replication.slave=false
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe using a `ternary` filter might help.

```
solr.replication.master={{ (ansible_eth0.ipv4.address == servermaster.eth0) | ternary('false', 'true') }}
solr.replication.slave=false
```

Answer (score 1):

As workaround you can add to your template

```
{% raw %}{% endraw %}
```