# What whitespace modifier am I missing?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I can't get this jinja2 template to work. Can somebody help me out?
I've tried the Jinja2 Live templater but I don't get the result I need.

Let's say I have the following group_vars/all.yml file:

```
disk_iops: 500
disk_space: 
  "C:": 10
  "D:": 10
  "E:": 10
core_count: 8
```

And the following template: name.json.j2

```
{
  "DiskIO": "{{ disk_iops }}",
  {% if disk_space is defined and disk_space -%}
  "DiskSpace": {
    {%- set comma = joiner(",") -%}
    {%- for key, value in disk_space.items() -%}
    {{ comma() }}
    "{{ key }}": "{{ value }}"
    {%- endfor %}
  },
  {% endif -%}
  "CoreCount": "{{ core_count }}"
}
```

I get the following result:

```
{
  "DiskIO": "500",
  "DiskSpace": {
    "C:": "70",
    "D:": "100",
    "E:": "10"  },
  "CoreCount": "4"
}
```

But I would like the `}` to be on a new line

Comment: I think that `-%}` the dash removes the whitespaces. Try removing it and see.

Comment: FWIW, using a Jinja template to create YAML/JSON is a bit misdirected. You should simply create the data structure as dict/list and encode it with the appropriate library call.

Comment: @deceze Could you ellaborate? I'm new with this and I am not sure what 'as  dict/list and encode it with the appropriate library call.' is.

Comment: as @deceze said, you should try dumping the json directly. And if you want it to be pretty, you could always use the `indent` option and set the `level`, like `json.dump(obj, fp, indent=4)`

Comment: @hansolo I'm not actually writing python code, but using ansible.

Comment: May be you check following stackoverflow link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350175/how-do-i-get-an-ansible-template-to-honor-new-lines-after-a-conditional

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution after all...

```
{
  "DiskIO": "{{ disk_iops }}",
  {% if disk_space is defined and disk_space -%}
  "DiskSpace": {
    {%- set comma = joiner(",") -%}
    {%- for key, value in disk_space.items() -%}
    {{ comma() }}
    "{{ key }}": "{{ value }}"
    {%- endfor %}

  },
  {% endif -%}
}
```